# Safari won't download files, not enough free space when plenty after Catalina upgrade

Tags: safari, catalina

I've had a search on the forums and the internet but couldn't find an answer to my issue.

Just updated my OSX to Catalina. I'm having a problem with Safari, when I try and download a file it tells me that there isn't enough space and to delete files. My SSD and my removable volume have more than enough space. As I only have a 128gb Macbook Pro I use an SD card as an overflow and this is where my download folder directs to. If I download using 'download file as..' and select the main SSD, it downloads fine. It just won't let me access the SD card. Chrome works fine.

If somebody could point me in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I think it has something to do with my link to my downloads folder. I made it quite a while ago. Think it is an alias?

Comment: If you use Finder, can you then create new directories on the SD card? - I'm wondering if perhaps it has been put in read-only mode.

Comment: I have full access to the SD card. Can write delete etc. If I change the download folder in the preferences to another folder on the SD it works. Change it back to the downloads folder, which is a symlink, it work ok. But if I come back to safari later it gives my the can't download error.